# Contruct Scala class from ClassTag

Tags: scala

The code below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve. I have a container class `Properties` that holds at most instance of many different subclasses of `Property`. I have generic `add` and `get` methods that work well to set and retrieve these properties.

However, if a property class does not exist in the `Properties` object, I want to be able to return a new instance which is created simply by calling the constructor of that class with its default parameters. See the comment below in the `getOrDefault` method for an idea of what i'm trying.

**EDIT**
I can do this if I require a zero-argument constructor as suggested in the comments, although I'd like to avoid this if possible.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

trait Property {}

object Properties {
  type PropertyTag = ClassTag[_ <: Property]
  type PropertyMap = Map[PropertyTag, Property]
}

import Properties._

final case class Properties(
    var properties: PropertyMap = Map.empty[PropertyTag, Property]
) {
  def add[S <: Property](prop: S)(implicit tag: ClassTag[S]): Unit = {
    properties += (tag -> prop)
  }

  def get[S <: Property](implicit tag: ClassTag[S]): S = {
    properties(tag).asInstanceOf[S]
  }

  def getOrDefault[S <: Property](implicit tag: ClassTag[S]): S = {
    if (properties.contains(tag)) {
      properties(tag).asInstanceOf[S]
    } else {
      // This does not work since the TestProperty2 has parameters
      tag.runtimeClass.newInstance.asInstanceOf[S]
    }
  }
}

final case class TestProperty() extends Property {}
final case class TestProperty2(val x) extends Property {
  def this() = this(3)
}

val properties = Properties()
properties.add(TestProperty())
val prop = properties.get[TestProperty]
val prop2 = properties.getOrDefault[TestProperty2]
println(prop2)
```

Comment: One solution would be to require no parameter constructor on all `Properties`.  `TextProperty2` will then have an auxiliary no parameter constructor, since constructor with default parameters is not the same thing

Comment: @EugeneRyzhikov Good thought. That does work although I would prefer to avoid if possible.

Comment: It might be possible with Scala reflection, i.e. find all default values and pass them into constructor, but it's going to be a lot more complex.

Comment: @EugeneRyzhikov That was my next thought, although from I've seen, that might be more messy.

Comment: Strongly suggest you create your own typeclass with a `create` method rather than using `ClassTag` and `newInstance` directly. And to match `Map` you should probably have `get` return an `Option` and use `apply` for the unsafe version.

Comment: @Tim Probably a good idea to match map. For now I added a `getOrNone` method which matches the `get` behavior of `Map`.